# Data scraping help html and javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am scraping data using fetch and out from [here](https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries) .

```
fetch("https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries/tur")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((out) => {

                    var confirmed = out.cases
                    var deaths = out.deaths
                    var recovered = out.recovered

                })
```

How can i access the data for one country (e.g *Turkey's*) from the link?

Comment: Its array. You need to index it. If you don’t know index, use `findIndex` method. Or directly `find`

Comment: I dont know what should i do, can you write example with using 3-4 country's datas ?

Comment: `let china = out.find(entry=>entry.country == ‘China‘)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `turkey`'s data you can simply update url like:

```
https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries/turkey
```

and then get data like:

```js
(async() => {
  fetch("https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries/turkey")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {

      var confirmed = out.cases
      var deaths = out.deaths
      var recovered = out.recovered

      console.log(confirmed, deaths, recovered)
    });
})();
```

If you need multiple countries data you can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method like:

```js
(async() => {
  fetch("https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
      var turkey = out.find(({country}) => country === 'Turkey')
      //var {cases, deaths, recovered} = turkey;
      var trcases = turkey.cases
      var trdeaths = turkey.deaths
      var trrecovered = turkey.recovered
      console.log(trcases, trdeaths, trrecovered);

      var italy = out.find(({country}) => country === 'Italy');
      //({cases, deaths, recovered} = italy);
      var itcases = italy.cases
      var itdeaths = italy.deaths
      var itrecovered = italy.recovered
      console.log(itcases, itdeaths, itrecovered)
    });
})();
```

Comment: what is the 'var turkey = out.find(({country}) => country === 'Turkey')
       var {cases, deaths, recovered} = turkey;' variable name? for example i want to print turkey's cases, what should i send to getElementById ?

Comment: `turkey` variable has the turkey related data you can acces it like `turkey.cases` but using object destructing we can get all data in one line. So, to print turkey's cases `console.log(cases)` will work. same way `console.log(deaths)` or you can print in one line like `console.log(cases, deaths, recovered)`

Comment: Basically `var {cases, deaths, recovered} = turkey;` means `var cases = turkey.cases;
var deaths = turkey.deaths;
var recovered = turkey.recovered;` in one line.

Comment: got it but i want to special variable's because i need like that. for example trcases,trdeaths,trrecovered because i will use them in between <script> tag.

Comment: I have updated code, you can update variable names as you like.

Comment: Special thanks to you! The new code worked!, so only one question left what is the console.log ? when i was delete it, the code working clearly.

Comment: Console log is used by developers for debugging code purpose. It just prints the variable passed in the browser cosole.